# How to save content of the QSettings file on Android to make it readable after updating my app from Play Store?

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

I have an application written in C++. It bases on Qt5.3 framework. I save settings of my app with `QSettings`. It works if I only restart my app. But if I redeploy my app from Qt Creator or update it from Play Market `QSettings` resets to initial state. I thinks the file associated with `QSettings` is removing.

I create `QSettings` with following code:

```
QSettings settings( QStringLiteral( "Company" ), QStringLiteral( "App" ), nullptr);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to specify the location of the setting file to a writable location which exists even if the application is removed :

```
#include <QSettings>
#include <QStandardPaths>

QString path ;
QString filename;

path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation) ;
filename = “config.ini” ;
QSettings settings(path + “/”+ filename,QSettings::IniFormat) ;
```

Here `QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation` returns a directory location where persistent data shared across applications can be stored and it is never empty.

Also you can set the application and organization name in the main of your application once :

```
qApp->setOrganizationName("Company");
qApp->setApplicationName("App");
```

Comment: Thanks! But it works on my device only with QStandardPaths::GenericDataLocation .